# Is this export syntax valid in ES2015?

Tags: javascript

Is the following use of destructuring assignment valid when used with `export` in ES2015?

```
// bam.js
const bam = { foo() {}, bar() {} };

export { foo, bar } = bam;


// another.js    
import { foo, bar } from 'bam';
```

Comment: No: https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-exports, [babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code_lz=KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMwhANHARgQynAXzgF5scBbAbiA&playground=true). The `{...}` part in an `export` declaration has nothing to do with destructuring, even though it uses similar syntax.

Comment: You can check things like this for yourself quite easily using the online Babel REPL: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Creact&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBARgQwLYwLwwN4wGYhACgEpMBfAGngQCcjSYSBuAWAChWBTADwAcQrYsuEBURV6aSkgZA

Comment: Okay thank you. The difficulty of checking this spurred the question, so that's useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The [specification](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-exports) requires `export` to be followed by

- `default ...`
- a declaration (class, function)
- variable statement (`var`, `let`, `const`)
- an export clause (`{}`, `{foo, bar}`, ...)
- ... (more but not relevant)

`{ foo, bar } = bam` however would an **assignment**, and none of the rules in the spec matches that use case.

To verify whether syntax that is not widely support is valid, you can use the [Babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code_lz=KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgMwhANHARgQynAXzgF5scBbAbiA&playground=true).